# How to keep a specific value selected in a select HTML control in following scenario?

Tags: php, html-select, smarty, selected

I'm using PHP, Smarty and MySQL for my website. I'm having a select control. The code for it is as follows:

```
<select name="contact_label" id="set_contact_label">
  <option value=""> -- Select label-- </option>
  {if $enquiries_labels}
    {foreach from=$enquiries_labels item=label key=key}
  <option value="{$key}" {if $contact_label == $key} selected="selected" {/if}>{$label}</option>
    {/foreach}
  {/if}
</select>
```

Equivalent HTML output is as follows:

```
<select name="contact_label" id="contact_label">
  <option value=""> -- Select label-- </option>
  <option value="0" selected="selected">New Enquiry</option>
  <option value="1" >Retail Enquiry</option>
  <option value="2" >Feedback</option>
  <option value="3" >Payment Query</option>
  <option value="4" >Package Query</option>
  <option value="5" >Test Query</option>
</select>
```

Now my issue is I want the option **--Select label--** selected by default when the if condition gets failed. If the if condition is satisfied then that option value should get selected. Now what's happening is the value **"New Enquiry"** is kept selected in the select box when the if condition fails. Actually I want the value --Select label-- to be selected by default when the if condition fails. I tried a lot to achieve this but couldn't succeed. Can anyone please help me in this regard?

Comment: Dunno if smarty could do it, but you can test if `in_array()` the $contact_label in the $enquiries_labels, and if NOT then add selected to the first option. I know there's a `{php}` block in smarty, but you are not suggested to use it. Find a built-in function for in_array in Smarty. Also you can do this with javascript. Parse the whole select box, and if non `selected` attribute, append one to the first option.

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe there's more elegant way, but since maybe you do not want to overload the server side you can use javascript to find if any of the elements has selected attr, and if none - to add to the first one.

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    var opts = document.getElementById("contact_label").options;
    var i, len = opts.length;
    var hasAttr = false;
        for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (opts[i].getAttribute("selected" ) != null ) {
                hasAttr = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!hasAttr) {
            $("select option[value='']").attr("selected","selected");
        }
    });
</script>
```

This might be overcomplicated, I tried it this way, because just ussing prop() or attr() will add `selected` attribute, but if you select manualy another one the parser will think this option has `selected` attribute and after refresh it won't get the real option which has the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a strict comparison operator:

```
{if $contact_label === $key}
```

also, have you tried using [{html_options}](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.html.options.tpl)? not sure, as I seldom use a 0 index value in my selects, but it probably already takes care of it.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this
In php file you need :

$smarty->assign('MyArray',$enquiries_labels);
$smarty->assign('selectedOption',0);

Now in template

```
<select name="contact_label" id="set_contact_label"> 
            <option value="0">Please Select label</option> 
            {html_options options=$MyArray selected=$selectedOption}
        </select>
```

Comment: you could supply array for selectedOption in html option