# Why the condition is getting satisfied even after not assigning a value to a variable in smarty template?

Tags: php, foreach, smarty

I'm assigning an array to a smarty template as follows:

```
    $enquiries_labels = array("0"=>"New Enquiry",
                                                        "1"=>"Retail Enquiry",
                                                        "2"=>"Feedback",
                                                        "3"=>"Payment Query",
                                                        "4"=>"Package Query",
                                                        "5"=>"Test Query");

$smarty->assign('enquiries_labels',  $enquiries_labels);
```

Now my smarty template code is as follows:

```
    <select name="contact_label" id="contact_label">
      <option value="" {if $contact_label == ''} selected="selected" {/if}>All</option>
       {if $enquiries_labels}
         {foreach from=$enquiries_labels item=label key=key}
         <option value="{$key}" {if $contact_label == $key} selected="selected" {/if}>{$label}</option>
         {/foreach}
       {/if}
   </select>
```

I'm not geting if I'm not assigning a value to a variable $contact_label in a PHP file then why the option `New Enquiry` having key `0` is selected by default. Actually it should have value "All" selected by default. Can anyone help me in this regard please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this is because of type conversion empty $contact_label comparing with integer converts to 0 and {if $contact_label == $key} is true for $key==0
When several options have selected="selected" the last one is actually selected

Comment: yes that's the possibility I also think. then what could be the solution for it? do you have any good idea?

Comment: Try using === instead of == in condition

Comment: and(or) {if ! isset($contact_label)} in first option

Comment: I answered that same question from your other account PHPGeek several days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969801/how-to-keep-a-specific-value-selected-in-a-select-html-control-in-following-scen/20977243#20977243. Please, try to not duplicate the same questions.